# Determine if XML Element with specific value is present using XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath

I googled the following but I don't get an aswer. Maybe my wording for this is not correct. I cannot believe that I am the only one who is trying to do this. Appologies if this is an easy question

I have an XML like this

```
<responseMessage>
<list>
    <reason>RC1</reason>
    <value>
        <id>1</id>          
    </value>

</list>
<list>
    <reason>RC2</reason>
    <value>
        <id>2</id>
    </value>
</list>
<list>
    <reason>RC3</reason>
    <value>
        <id>3</id>
    </value>
</list>
<list>
    <reason>RC4</reason>
    <value>
        <id>3</id>
    </value>
</list>
```

What XPath expression can I use to test if a List Element is present with sub child where the id of a value is 3? The order of the list is undeterminend and can be the first List item now and the 2nd time it can be last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
boolean(//list/value/id[text()='3'])
```

you mean? Here the `boolean()` function converts the result to `true` or `false`. An empty result is `false` and a result of one or more elements evaluates to `true`.
Or even simpler:

```
//list/value/id/text()='3'
```